# Difference-in-differences model with a matched control group

Tags: regression, causality, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores, matching

I need to run a difference-in-differences (DiD) model, but I'm not sure how to construct a formula for this. The problem is that the timing of events affecting the treatment group is not uniform, like in a traditional DiD model.

[image]

The table attached is a panel data for different firms and I would like to find out the impact of firms issuing special reports in (1) firm-years when auditors have determined that firms' controls are not working properly and (2) during years when the auditors in the previous year assessed the controls as ineffective and this year the firm receives the same assessment from auditors. The formula would need to look something like this:

Future earnings = SR + notworking + SR * notworking + controls,

where the interaction variable SR*notworking would be the variable of interest. The same would need to be repeated for firms that receive the same assessment again:

Future earnings = SR + notfixed + SR * notfixed + controls.

I would be comparing the results to a control group that has been matched using propensity score (PS) matching. I have already done the PS matching, but I'm not sure about the formulas. Are there any better ways to assess the effect of SR * notworking on future earnings, when compared to the (PS matched) control group of firms? As suggested to me I will need to create pseudo-treatment years for control groups, but I'm not sure how to do that.